# Find objects in an array that are the same, not remove them

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to find objects in an array that are the same to flag them in the UI.  I can't seem to use undescore to do it.

I was doing this:

```
var a = [ {'id': 1, 'name': 'jake' }, {'id':4, 'name': 'jenny'},  {'id': 9, 'name': 'nick'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'jake' } ];
var eaches = _.each(a, function (obj) {
  _.find(a, function () {
    return _.isEqual(a, obj);
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Find duplicates in `a` so you'd find `{'id': 1, 'name': 'jake' }`?

Comment: @muistooshort yes, i'm trying to find all the duplicates, like if there was an additional jenny object, it'd find that one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need something like this:

```
var a = [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'jake'
}, {
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'jenny'
}, {
    'id': 9,
    'name': 'nick'
}, {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'jake'
}];

var eq = [];

_.each(a, function (x, i) {
    var e = _.find(a, function (y, j) {
        return i !== j && _.isEqual(x, y);
    });
    if (e) {
        eq.push(x);
    }
});

console.log(eq);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/WBbs5/

---

**UPDATE:**
Custom "`_.uniq`" based on `_.isEqual` instead of `===` strict comparison:

```
var uniqEq = _.reject(eq, function(x, i) {
    return _.find(eq, function(y, j) {
        return i < j && _.isEqual(x, y);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/hzBBA/

Comment: Is there a reason why on this output, if I do _.uniq(eq), it doesn't remove multiple jake objects?

Comment: Because `_.uniq` uses strict `===` comparison and so if two objects are equal, they though are different references.

Comment: Can you also explain the return statement.  I don't understand why i!==j is there.  Thanks!

Comment: Because when you're searching using `_.find` you need to be sure that you found not the same element (`x`), and the element at different index but which is equal to current one. So the condition is to have `x` and `y` in different "cells".